# My old employer is still sending emails from my email account 2 years later

Tags: email

I was let go almost 2 years ago and my old employer is still sending emails, as though they were from me, to my old customers.  Is that legal?

Comment: While the ethics of their doing this are quite questionable, they actually "own" your email address that is associated with their company domain.  In other words, they can do this.

Comment: @jwh20 Perhaps so, but can you cite law or case law that says so?

Comment: No, that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @jwh20, it might depend on where the OP and the company are. When they use the email to *send* messages, and not just forward incoming messages to customer service, they are pretending that the OP still works there.

Answer (score 2):

### It’s not, and never was, your email address

And, incidentally, the emails sent and received by it are not your emails. They all belong to your employer.

For a time, they allowed you to use it. Now, someone else is using it. No laws are being broken.

However, if they are using it in such away to create the impression that you still work there or in a way that damages your reputation then we are heading into fraud and defamation territory respectively. The first is none of your business, that’s between your ex-employer and whoever they are sending emails to. The second you can bring suit over.

Comment: Most corporate email addresses are based on the name of the employee, so the last paragraph almost certainly applies.

Comment: @Acccumulation actually... numerically, most are Position/department@company.domain

Comment: @Trish Any cite for that? I wouldn't be surprised that most external emails are from that sort of address, but I would be surprised by this being the majority of addresses.

Comment: @Acccumulation technically... *anything*@company.domain is a valid e-mail, just most servers are set up to flat out refuse such mail. that nonsense mails are the absolute largest namespace... but as said, most are outright refused.

Comment: @Trish I have never had an e-mail address based on anything other than my name.  Does your e-mail address change every time your title changes?

Comment: @phoog My work email address is just my employee number. There's *also* an email that is redirected to me which is my job title and I get the mails to my department, and the company wide ones that are just addressed to *All.keyword@company.domain"